# linux find files and copy to directory

Tags: linux, bash

I try to find files in a directory and copy them to somewhere else, this is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# fileSearch

array=(a b c d)

for var in array
do
        find ~/ -name $var* -exec cp {} ./test/ \;
done
```

What am i doing wrong? He won't find any files...
I think it probably will be something with quotes.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Debug tip: change shebang into `#!/bin/bash -x` and investigate the output

Comment: @Fredrik: Better to use `set -x` instead, your approach is not portable.

Comment: True, but [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) untill needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# fileSearch

array=(a b c d)

for var in array
do
    echo $var
done
```

Output:

```
array
```

In other words, you're just looping through a word-list which contains a single word "array". The correct version should expand the array, and add a `$`-symbol (meaning to reference the variable):

```
#!/bin/bash
# fileSearch

array=(a b c d)

for var in ${array[@]}
do
    find ~/ -name "$var*" -exec cp {} ./test/ \;
done
```

Also it's a good habit to quote your variables, i.e., whenever you use a variable like `$var`, use `"$var"` instead. This prevents many problems for when your variables contain strings with spaces (or other "strange" symbols) that should be treated as a single string.